# app crash when presenting view controller after loadViewIfNeed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to present a view controller with custom animation, so I came up with this code. When I tried to present the view controller, I got no error but the app crashes. Can someone tell me why my app crashes?

My code looks like this

```
func presentLeftToRight<T>(viewName: String, class: T.Type) where T: DefaultView {

    let presentView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewName) as! T

    presentView.loadViewIfNeeded()
    presentView.topContainer.alpha = 0
    presentView.bgMenuView.alpha = 0
    presentView.mainButton.alpha = 0

    self.view.insertSubview(presentView.view, belowSubview: scrollView)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.scrollView.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.present(presentView, animated: false, completion: nil)
    })

}
```

Comment: it could be because your storyboard object is nil? have you tried putting a print() statement after `let presentView = ...` to see if your `presentView` is not nil?

Comment: @RX9 I already tried `print(presentView)` and it does have a value `<myapp.MainView: 0x119840c00>`.

Comment: What's the crash message? Which line causes the crash? Please put these details in your question.

Comment: What you are doing is very wrong. You are manually adding `presentView.view` to the current view and then you also present the `presentView` controller. That's is not a good idea. It's also a really bad design to access the subviews of another view controller from another class. It breaks encapsulation and makes for really fragile code.

Comment: @rmaddy It does not have any message in the output console. The app just crashes immediately right after the animation completed. I think `self.present(presentView, animated: false, completion: nil)` causes the crash because when I comment that line, everything works just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy Do you have any suggestions instead of the way I'm doing right now? I'm kinda a newbie of swift developer.

Comment: Look into the `modalPresentationStyle` property and the `custom` style. Search on custom transitions.

Comment: i am not sure but your `compilation` in coming background try to in main Thread using `Dispatch`, in compilation Handler use `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.present(presentView, animated: false, completion: nil) }`

Comment: @PradipPatel No need. The completion block of a UIView animation will always be called on the main queue. If that was the problem there would have been an error about running UI code on a background queue.